# Reply to Tweet with Tweepy - Python

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

I can't seem to get tweepy to work with replying to a specific tweet:

```
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET)
auth.set_access_token(ACCESS_KEY, ACCESS_SECRET)

api = tweepy.API(auth)

### at this point I've grabbed the tweet and loaded it to JSON...

tweetId = tweet['results'][0]['id']

api.update_status('My status update',tweetId)
```

The api says it takes optional parameters and in_reply_to_status_id is the first, but it seems to be ignoring it altogether. This script will post an updated status, but it does not link it as a reply to the tweetId that I'm passing.

API for reference: http://code.google.com/p/tweepy/wiki/APIReference#update_status

Anyone have any ideas? I feel like I'm missing something simple here...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well then, it was something simple. I had to specify who the tweet was directed towards using the @ notation.

    api.update_status('My status update @whoIReplyTo',tweetId)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Well then, it was something simple. I had to specify who the tweet was directed towards using the @ notation.

```
api.update_status('My status update @whoIReplyTo',tweetId)
```

Comment: Worked first time. I was missing the tweet id number. Great question and answer - thanks!

Answer (score 38):

Just posting the solution so no someone else suffers the way I did.
Twitter updated the API and added an option named `auto_populate_reply_metadata`

All you need to do is set that to true, and the leave the rest as should be. Here is a sample:

```
api.update_status(status = 'your reply', in_reply_to_status_id = tweetid , auto_populate_reply_metadata=True)
```

Also, the status_id is the long set of digits at the end of the tweet URL. Good Luck!

Comment: This probably should be the new answer. Thanks.

Comment: does this solution leave a comment in a tweet? can this function do "quote retweet"?

Answer (score 24):

I ran into the same problem, but luckily I found the solution. You just need to include the user's screen_name in the tweet:

```
api.update_status('@<username> My status update', tweetId)
```

Comment: Spent hours trying to figure out the problem and finally found this solution! Thanks!

Comment: Same problem here...this is the only answer which worked for me.  Thank you buddy!

Comment: THnaks a lot buddy !

Answer (score 18):

You can also do

```
api.update_status("my update", in_reply_to_status_id = tweetid)
```

Comment: THis should be the best option

Comment: This did not work for me. You do need to add the user's handle in the Tweet for it to be  a reply. Otherwise it will count as a new Tweet from you, not a reply to an existent Tweet.

Comment: @DiegoMoraCespedes This is wrong (at least now it is). You have to add `auto_populate_reply_metadata=True` along with `in_reply_to_status_id`. This means that you *don't* have to add the user's handle in the Tweet in order for it to work.

Answer (score 2):

I discovered that I had to include the tweet's ID string (rather than actual ID number) when specifying the tweet that I was replying to

```
api.update_status('@whoIReplyTo my reply tweet',tweetIdString)
```

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a bug in Tweepy – even if you make a call to **api.update_status** with the correct parameters set,

```
api.update_status(status=your_status, in_reply_to_status=tweet_to_reply_to.id)
```

the tweet will not be a reply. In order to get a reply, you need to mention the user you want to reply to **AND** specify the correct in_reply_to_status id.

```
reply_status = "@%s %s" % (username_to_reply_to, your_status)
api.update_status(status=reply_status, in_reply_to_status=tweet_to_reply_to.id)
```

Keep in mind though – Tweepy and Twitter's servers still enforce a maximum number of 140 characters, so make sure you check that

```
len(reply_status) <= 140
```

Again, I think this is a bug because on the Twitter app, you can reply without embedding the username of the person to whom you're replying.

Answer (score 1):

```
reply_status = "@%s %s" % (tweet.user.screen_name, "type your reply here")
api.update_status(status=reply_status, in_reply_to_status_id=tweet.id)
```

this is the last correct form, I just test it a few minutes ago