# How to read Twitter's Streaming API and reply an user based on a certain keyword?

Tags: python, api, twitter, stream, tweepy

I am implementing a Twitter bot for fun purposes using `Tweepy`.

What I am trying to code is a bot that tracks a certain keyword and based in it the bot replies the user that tweeted with the given string.

I considered storing the Twitter's Stream on a `.json` file and looping the Tweet object for every user but it seems impractical as receiving the stream locks the program on a loop.

So, how could I track the tweets with the Twitter's Stream API based on a certain keyword and reply the users that tweeted it?

Current code:

```
    from tweepy import OAuthHandler
    from tweepy import Stream
    from tweepy.streaming import StreamListener

class MyListener(StreamListener):
    def on_data(self, data):
        try:
            with open("caguei.json", 'a+') as f:
                f.write(data)
                data = f.readline()
                    tweet = json.loads(data)
                    text = str("@%s acabou de. %s " % (tweet['user']['screen_name'], random.choice(exp)))
                    tweepy.API.update_status(status=text, in_reply_to_status_id=tweet['user']['id'])
                #time.sleep(300)
                return True
        except BaseException as e:
            print("Error on_data: %s" % str(e))
        return True
    def on_error(self, status):
        print(status)
        return True

    api = tweepy.API(auth)
    twitter_stream = Stream(auth, MyListener())

    twitter_stream.filter(track=['dengue']) #Executing it the program locks on a loop
```

Comment: Can't you simply do that in the *on_data* function of you *MyListener* ?

Comment: @SpiXel not sure how to use the API correctly. I do not have much experience in API's

Comment: @SpiXel Oh, I think I managed to understand. The method on_data runs while receiving the Twitter's stream. I thought it was just a random name. I think I can accomplish what I am intended.

Comment: @SpiXel Not yet! I understood the logic but I am facing another problem. While writing the data received and trying to read it immediately from the json file I receive the error "No JSON object could be decoded". What is wrong? I can read the same json file in another script but on the on_data method it seems I can't. I updated the code.

Comment: Check that caguei.json does not already contain anything. Since you're opening the file with "a+", you might be reading something totally different than what you intend to read with *f.readline()*. Also it's probably wrong and not what you want. Since on each input, you're a opening the file, appending the new data to the end of it (a+ mode), But reading the same old first line again and again. It's probably not what you intend.

Comment: @SpiXel Managed. I think it was empty, not sure. It is know working. I just need to verify how to reply a tweet. I used the parameter in_reply_to_status_id=tweet['user']['id'] that is the id of the tweet but it is nit replying..

Comment: For that, check this question out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9322465/reply-to-tweet-with-tweepy-python

Comment: @SpiXel Done. Everything working perfectly. Thanks!

Comment: Sure, Glad it helped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tweepy `StreamListener` class allows you to override it's `on_data` method. That's where you should be doing your logic.

As per the code

```
class StreamListener(object):

    ... 

    def on_data(self, raw_data):
        """Called when raw data is received from connection.

        Override this method if you wish to manually handle
        the stream data. Return False to stop stream and close connection.
        """
        ...
```

So in your listener, you can override this method and do your custom logic.

```
class MyListener(StreamListener):

    def on_data(self, data):

         do_whatever_with_data(data)
```

You can also override several other methods (*on_direct_message*, etc) and I encourage you to take a look at the code of **StreamListener**.

Update

Okay, you can do what you intent to do with the following:

```
class MyListener(StreamListener):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyListener, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.file = open("whatever.json", "a+")

    def _persist_to_file(self, data):
        try:
            self.file.write(data)
        except BaseException:
            pass

    def on_data(self, data):
        try:
            tweet = json.loads(data)
            text = str("@%s acabou de. %s " % (tweet['user']['screen_name'], random.choice(exp)))
            tweepy.API.update_status(status=text, in_reply_to_status_id=tweet['user']['id'])
            self._persist_to_file(data)
            return True
        except BaseException as e:
            print("Error on_data: %s" % str(e))
        return True

    def on_error(self, status):
        print(status)
        return True
```