# Tweepy - Reply only to Tweet author

Tags: python, api, twitter, bots, tweepy

I use Tweepy to reply to certain Tweets as a bot on Twitter. I would like the reply to be addressed only to the author of the Tweet and not to any other users that may be mentioned in it.

Currently I use this to reply:

```
reply_status = api.update_status(status = 'tweet content', in_reply_to_status_id = tweet.id, auto_populate_reply_metadata=True)
```

This call replies to all users mentioned in the original tweet. I've noticed there is an `exclude_reply_user_ids=` option in the `update_status` function. This however requires a list of user IDs to exclude.

1. How do I get a list of user IDs mentioned in a Tweet?
2. Is there a simpler way to reply only to the author?

I would like to avoid having to write the username at the beginning of the Tweet, which I would need to do if I didn't use `auto_populate_reply_metadata=True` (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47159329/10365325)).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How do I get a list of user ids mentioned in a tweet?

You can use the `entities` attribute of the Status/[Tweet object](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/v1/data-dictionary/object-model/tweet), which is an [Entities object](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/v1/data-dictionary/object-model/entities#entitiesobject) with a `user_mentions` attribute. This will give you an array of [User mention objects](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/v1/data-dictionary/object-model/entities#mentions), and you can use the `id` or `id_str` fields of each one.

> Is there a simpler way to reply only to the author?
>
> I would like to avoid having to write the username at the beginning of the tweet, which I would need to do if I didn't use `auto_populate_reply_metadata=True`

Yes, by manually including the mention at the start of the Tweet.
You can do this programatically by retrieving the screen name of the author of the Tweet, e.g. `tweet.user.screen_name`.

Otherwise, if you're using `auto_populate_reply_metadata`, the only way to exclude mentions is using `exclude_reply_user_ids`.

Comment: Thanks. It appears that the ```user_mentions``` attribute only lists users mentioned explicitly within the tweet body. I am looking for a list of all users in the tweet (including the author and any previous repliers).

Comment: It should include the users being replied to as well, and like I said, if you're using `auto_populate_reply_metadata`, the only way to exclude mentions is using `exclude_reply_user_ids`.

Comment: `user_mentions` only includes users mentioned in the tweet body (see [here](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/v1/data-dictionary/object-model/entities#mentions)).